Is it possible to use a bluetooth keyboard with react-native-ble-plx without telling the phone it's a keyboard?
Hear me out, I promise this will make sense.

Context:
Usually when connecting a bluetooth keyboard to a mobile device (via the settings) the virtual keyboard hides itself. They cannot be used simultaniously. This is an intended feature and there is no way to pragmatically disable this behaviour.
This is a problem because my app requires access to both the virtual keyboard and physical keyboard simultaniously, because I need to trigger functions remotely using the keyboard as a controller.
Idea:
I'm looking at ways to hook up the bluetooth keyboard without telling the phone it's a keyboard. So as far as the phone is concerned, it's just a big row of buttons, right?
My theory is that if I connect to the keyboard via my app using react-native-ble-plx, there might be a way to make it so that the phone doesn't know it's a keyboard and therefore won't hide the virtual keyboard.
TL;DR: Can I connect disguise a bluetooth keyboard as a humble "panel of buttons" using react-native-ble-plx?
I'm a total rookie working on this app in my free time and I can tell from the docs this is going to be a huge learning curve for me. Before I sink a week or two into a dead end, I was hoping someone familiar with the library could tell me if this plan is worth investigating.
Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Is the keyboard even using BLE? Maybe it is a Bluetooth Classic Device. You could try to connect to it using a Bluetooth Serial Monitor
